# foreach trimming characters and I'm not telling it to!

Tags: php, foreach

I've cleaned this up to where I know there is an issue.  Bluntly I've got a foreach statement cutting off all by one character of the results.  Example in comments below.

```
print_r($getarticlemultiarray);

/// this print_r returns good values like [title] => titletext [body] => bodytext
foreach ($getarticlemultiarray as $zyz)  {
    echo $zyz['title'];
// here is the problem.  This echo statement is only throwing out 1 character
 // for example with the values in the example above it's just echoing a 't'.

}  // end foreach
```

This foreach is nested inside another one, but I'm not doing anything with string lengths, and I am not using $zyz anywhere else.  Nothing strange but normal words with no special characters either.

Comment: Can you give the exact output of your print_r, also try print_r($xyz) in the foreach loop and give that please?

Comment: I think you've "overcleaned" it - that example will work provided the `print_r` is as you describe. As such, you're doing something else that is causing the issue (or the correct bits are being `echo`'d but you can't see them due to CSS rendering issues etc.

Comment: If I do a print_r of print_r($zyz) it doesn't match up what I should be getting.  It's only got the title from the array.  But it's a full value - not cut off.  It should have the title and body values in there right?

Comment: @gww print_r($getarticlemultiarray); sends out: Array ( [title] => test [body] => dgdgdgaaggagtest )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have said, it looks like your print_r is essentially

```
Array (
   ['title'] => 'titletext',
   ['body'] => 'bodytext
)
```

In that case, your `foreach` is setting `$zyz` to `titletext` and `bodytext`, respectively.  These strings have no 'title' key.  PHP will treat these key as 0 which in turn returns the first character (hence why you see a 't').  Seems like you don't have to loop here.

Comment: Well I feel silly.  I was making the array like this  $getarticlemultiarray = array("title" => "$articletitle", "body" => "$articlesdisplay"); instead of like this $getarticlemultiarray[] = array("title" => "$articletitle", "body" => "$articlesdisplay");